# Copying files between S3 buckets -- only 2 files copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to copy multiple files from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket using lambda function but it is just copying 2 files in destination s3 bucket.

Here is my code:

```py
# using python and boto3
    
import json
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    destination_bucket_name = 'nishantnkd'
    copy_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_name}
    s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_object,
                              Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
        return {'statusCode': 3000,
                'body': json.dumps('File has been Successfully Copied')}
```

Comment: The Lambda function shown copies one object. Did you check CloudWatch Logs to see if it was invoked once per uploaded object? Did you log the `event` parameter to ensure that it's what you expected (i.e. one single object)? Were there any errors logged in CloudWatch Logs?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the Amazon S3 bucket is configured to trigger the AWS Lambda function when a new object is created.

When the Lambda function is triggered, it is possible that **multiple event records are sent to the function**. Therefore, **it should loop** through the event records like this:

```py
# using python and boto3
    
import json
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:  # This loop added
        source_bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        file_name = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key']) # Note this change too
        destination_bucket_name = 'nishantnkd'
        copy_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_name}
        s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_object, Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
    return {'statusCode': 3000,
            'body': json.dumps('File has been Successfully Copied')}
```

Comment: That's the exact thing I want upvoted!