# How to replicate contents of a specific folder of a S3 bucket to another specific folder of a different S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have a requirement to replicate the contents of a specific folder of an S3 bucket to a different folder of another S3 bucket. Both S3 buckets reside in the same region and are owned by the same account.

Eg: Say I have an S3 bucket named "**ABC-Inbound**" and a folder inside called "**from_A**".
Also, I have another S3 bucket in the same region names **workloads** and a folder inside called "**A_data**"

Is it possible to write a Cloudformation replication rule to replicate the contents of the **from_A** folder to the **A_data** folder? I don't want to copy the entire folder just the contents only.

Tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough1.html) by adding a Filter to replication configuration, but that didn't work as it copied entire folder to other bucket.

```
    {
  "Role": "IAM-role-ARN",
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Priority": 1,
      "DeleteMarkerReplication": { "Status": "Disabled" },
      "Filter" : { "Prefix": "from_A/"},
      "Destination": {
        "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::workloads"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Afaik S3 replication does not support changing the prefix during replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 Replication will replicate objects between buckets and you can specify a Prefix to only replicate part of a bucket.

However, when replicating objects, S3 Replication will not change the `Key` (filename) of an object. The Key includes the full path of the object. This means that the source and destination folders will be the same.

If you must replicate to a different folder/path in the destination bucket, then you would need to manage the replication yourself, such as:

- Periodically run the `aws s3 sync` command to copy files between the buckets, or
- Create an AWS Lambda function that is triggered upon creation of an object in the source bucket. Code the Lambda function to copy the object to the destination bucket and path.

Here is an example of such a Lambda function: [Copying files between S3 buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72973799/174777)