# AWS S3 multi bucket replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

This is an extension of the question I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627069/how-to-replicate-contents-of-a-specific-folder-of-a-s3-bucket-to-another-specifi/76627138#76627138).

Is it possible to replicate 2 levels, meaning I have a source bucket (Customer's bucket) and an intermediate general bucket and a third specific bucket, I want to replicate objects from the customer's bucket to our intermediate **general** bucket and from there replicate to the specific bucket.

Eg: Bucket A is owned by the customer. Bucket B (the general bucket) and Bucket C (the specific bucket) are owned by us. The general B bucket contains everything sent(replicate from A bucket) by the customer, and from there, we want to replicate only a specific folder to the C bucket.

First replication: source A -> destination B

Second replication: source B -> destination C

I tried to simulate it by creating 3 buckets (in the same region under the same account) and adding replication configurations to A and B buckets, but it succeeded on the first replication only. didn't copy the objects into the C bucket.

Is this achievable with AWS S3 replications?

Comment: Have you considered replication from A to _both_ B and C? See: [New – Amazon S3 Replication Adds Support for Multiple Destination Buckets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-replication-adds-support-for-multiple-destination-buckets/)

Comment: In your test, if you manually upload an object to B, does it replicate to C?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Yes, replication from A to B and B to C are working individually. Replication from A to B and C is not an option. We must first get from A to B then B to C. I also saw [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-replicate-existing-objects-with-amazon-s3-batch-replication/#:~:text=Replicate%20replicas%20of%20objects%20that%20were%20created%20from%20a%20replication%20rule) that we cannot live replicate replicas of objects again.